# rvm -bash: cat -v: command not found

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, rvm

When I run `rvm`:

```
$ rvm
-bash: cat -v: command not found
```

Howevern, if I run `rvm -v`:

```
$ rvm -v

rvm 1.11.5 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io]
```

What's wrong?

```
$ which rvm
/Users/me/.rvm/bin/rvm
```

Comment: It looks like `rvm` is failing to run `cat -v`, not that `rvm` isn't found. `rvm -v` must not invoke `cat -v`. Why though, I'm not sure, just an observation.

Comment: `rvm` would have to be doing something pretty broken to try to run `cat -v` as a command instead of trying to run `cat` with the `-v` option.

Comment: Something is pretty messed up on your system if `cat` cannot be found.

Comment: `cat` is ok. btw, I _fixed_ the problem by `rvm get latest` but not sure what caused the original error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a bug in RVM:

```
"${PAGER:-"cat -v"}" ...
```

which was fixed in RVM stable.